# JavaEEアプリケーションでSpringBatchは使えるか？

Tags: java, spring, java-ee

JavaEEでアプリケーションを開発しています。
バッチ処理を作りたいのですが、JavaEEのjBatchではなく、SpringFrameworkのSpringBatchを使う、ということはできるのでしょうか？

Comment: SpringBatchもただのライブラリなので、普通にできると思いますけど。何か、特定のコンテナ上で動作させたいというような質問でしょうか。具体的に技術的に困っている点をもう少し書くといいかもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

使えるかどうかを知りたいということでしたら、使えます。

Java EEのjBatchの仕様は、Spring Batchを参考に策定されたので、アーキテクチャは似ています。ただし、Spring Batchの方が先につくられたので、jBatch(GlassFishやWildFlyに内包されているもの)より高機能なはずです。
ちなみに、Spring Batchもバージョン3からjBatchに準拠するように実装されています。